# How can I install PHP extension libsodium in Wampserver?

Tags: php, wampserver, php-extension, libsodium

I am trying to install the [Libsodium](https://pecl.php.net/package/libsodium) PHP extension using PECL, but I have no idea how to get the dll files needed. I want to use it with Wampserver on Windows 7 (64-bit).

Can any one help me?

Comment: try other version not the latest one ! i had the same problem with other php extension !

Comment: you mean wampserver's old version? Which one should I use?
and what are the next steps to be followed?

Comment: no the libsodium! try multiple version ! here is doc https://paragonie.com/book/pecl-libsodium

Comment: @mohsen.. I was referring to the same document. I am sorry, but I couldn't find how to install it in Wampserver. Can you guide me to any general doc regarding the same?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is How I did it.

1. Download the libsodium from here > [For PHP 7.0](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/libsodium/1.0.2/php_libsodium-1.0.2-7.0-ts-vc14-x64.zip), [For PHP 5.6](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/libsodium/1.0.2/php_libsodium-1.0.2-5.6-ts-vc11-x64.zip) And [For PHP 5.5](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/libsodium/1.0.2/php_libsodium-1.0.2-5.5-ts-vc11-x64.zip) (All x64). #One Important Note, Please download appropriate x86-32 bit or x64-64 bit of this extension matching of your environment from [here](https://pecl.php.net/package/libsodium/1.0.2/windows)
2. Extract the Downloaded file and copy **libsodium.dll** to **wamp->bin->php->php5(x).x.xx** Folder
3. Copy **php_libsodium.dll** From the extracted File to **wamp->bin->php->php5(x).x.xx ->ext**
4. Now Click on the WAMP System tray icon. 
   [image]
5. Go to **PHP-> PHP Settings** and Click on the **enable dl** from the menu of the WampManager from the system tray
6. Now Add bellow line to php.ini from **PHP -> php.ini** from the menu of Wampmanager, save and close it

> extension=php_libsodium.dll

7. Now Restart Apache or click Restart All Services from the menu of WampManager

You should now get your **php_libsodium** in the extensions of the php Up and Running.
:)

**I didn't notice that, this question is 4 months old. I hope You have solved this.

Comment: Turns out I was using the wrong version of the extension for the kind of PHP my choice of web dev environment bundle (XAMPP 5.6.15) came with. I had to use the [thread-safe 32-bit](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/libsodium/1.0.2/php_libsodium-1.0.2-5.6-ts-vc11-x86.zip) version to get it to work as intended. I suggest you add a note about needing the proper version into the answer to make it stand out from the other.

Answer (score 8):

### Wamp 3.2.0 64-bit

Even though in the past apparently more steps were required [(see my comment from 2018)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33007747/how-can-i-install-php-extension-libsodium-in-wampserver#comment91911901_33008246), today I installed Wamp 3.2.0 64-bit, and when I got an error about libsodium not working, I was able to easily fix it by:

1. Wamp tray icon > PHP > PHP Extensions > ensure "sodium" is checked
2. (Wamp will automatically refresh)

I was pleasantly surprised that is worked!

### Edit: 24th Feb, 2023

### WAMP 3.3.1 64-bit

Additional steps to follow when above two steps are not enough.

3. Run the cmd `php --ini` in terminal, and note the php.ini file path like `C:\wamp64\bin\php\php8.1.16\php.ini`
4. Locate and open php.ini file
5. Find and uncomment `extension=sodium`
6. Save the file and restart WAMP.

Comment: Thanks! Confirming that it works in Wamp 3.3.1 with PHP 8.1 in Feb 2023.

Answer (score 4):

You can download the dll files you need here: http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/libsodium/1.0.2/

1. Select the version that corresponds with your PHP version, compiler and architecture. (this can be checked using phpinfo(); on your machine)
2. Copy php_libsodium.dll to "ext" directory (C:\PHP\ext)
3. Copy libsodium.dll to root of PHP directory (C:\PHP)
4. Add extension=php_libsodium.dll to php.ini
5. restart apache

This worked on a standalone version of PHP running on Windows 7, I see no reason why this shouldn't work on WAMP or XAMP.

Comment: For Xampp users: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48287186/sodium-is-not-loading-on-xampp-php-7-2. See also my comment about Xampp 5.6.40

Answer (score 3):

> use command prompt :
>  
>   `pecl install libsodium`
>
> and go to wamp folder find php.ini in php folder : 
>   append this line: to ini file 
>   `extension=libsodium.so`

**You might be able to achieve this result by running php5enmod libsodium, depending on which webserver you use. Make sure you restart your webserver after installing PECL libsodium**

here is good references: 
https://paragonie.com/book/pecl-libsodium/read/00-intro.md#installing-libsodium

Comment: True... but only if I could get the dll file of my package. It is not available directly. Can you show me a way out to install the extensions which don't have a dll file.
Can you also specify in depth, where exactly should I type the command? Is there something for "PECL" that I have to install before typing this command.

Comment: This page didn't cover installing on Windows. An upcoming update should amend that deficiency. :)

Comment: Mine had to be `extension=sodium.so` instead (as mentioned here: https://paragonie.com/book/pecl-libsodium/read/00-intro.md).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use https://github.com/paragonie/sodium_compat. You can simply use :

```
 composer require paragonie/sodium_compat
```