# Sodium is not loading on XAMPP PHP 7.2

Tags: php, xampp, libsodium

Hey for some reason when i use XAMPP PHP 7.2, all of the sodium functions are not working. When i run `print_r(get_loaded_extensions());` it does not show sodium on the list. When i go to http://php.net/manual/en/sodium.installation.php it says no installation needed they are a part of the core. So i went to my `php.ini` configuration file and made sure that it did not disable sodium, it says `extension=php_sodium.dll`. I went to the console to double check to see if their were any errors, there was none. It was weird because `Argon2i` is working fine. The Argon2i constants are all defined and when used in the `password_hash()` function it generates a password hash no problem. I am using windows as my OS. Is there anything else that can cause something like this, any help would be nice. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure that you edit the correct php.ini?

Starting with PHP 7.2, ini file (at least on my Windows PC), the syntax to load extension is now `extension=modulename` instead of `extension=php_modulename.dll`.

Comment: I just uninstalled xampp and reinstalled it and sodium loaded. I did not know what i did but i could not replicate the error. Thanks for your help tho.

Answer (score 30):

For Windows XAMPP PHP 7.2.4, to correct the Error:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'sodium'
>   (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\sodium (The specified module could not be
>   found.), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_sodium.dll (The specified module could
>   not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0

There must be a copy of php/libsodium.dll (PHP *Extension*) in apache/bin/ (Apache *Module*). It is assumed, but not tested, that it must be same file.

Assuming that php/libsodium.dll and php/ext/php_sodium.dll are the same build, which is the case with a new install of XAMPP 7.2.4, the install is:

```
1. Add "extension=sodium" to php.ini (no quotes)
2. Copy php/libsodium.dll to apache/bin/
3. Restart Server
```

Comment: This also sorted it for me. I was on XAMPP 7.2.6. Could not get it to work. Removed that and installed XAMPP 7.2.16. Followed the steps. Libsodium now works.

Comment: Thank you so so much, was suck on this for hours and nothing was working, until  followed your steps.

Comment: A very important information for Xampp 5.6.40 users: the last version of this extension that works with this package is 1.0.5, and NOT 1.0.6, as stated in PECL site!

Answer (score 12):

Open php.ini file from C:\xampp\php\ -> under ***Dynamic Extensions*** and add

```
extension=sodium
```

Comment: After trying a lot of solutions this one worked smoothly, thanks

Comment: @sohailamar happy coding

Answer (score 5):

I encountered the same problem, but reinstall XAMPP 7.2 doesn't help.
Finally, I returned to XAMPP 7.1.14 then installed sodium additionally, and it  works.

1. [Install XAMPP](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Windows/7.1.14/)(xampp-**win32-7.1.14-0-VC14**)
2. [Download libsodium](https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/libsodium/) named php_libsodium-2.0.9-**7.1-ts-vc14-x86**.zip
3. Rename php_sodium.dll to php_libsodium.dll, then put it into C:\xampp\php\ext
4. Put libsodium.dll into C:\xampp\apache\bin
5. Add into php.ini: `extension=php_libsodium.dll`

I know rollback is not a good idea.
But at least it works for me.

Comment: The extension should be named sodium not libsodium for PHP => 7.0.

Comment: Check you libsodium version.

Comment: What I wrote above is working here. So I'm not going to reinstall 7.2 again. [imgur capture](https://imgur.com/a/Rjzax)

Answer (score 5):

**This will work for wamp also**

check-in PHP module if sodium is available or not with the following command

```
cmd> php -m
cmd> php --ri sodium
```

if sodium is not listed then go to your /php/php.ini and search for ';extension=sodium' and remove ';'
you will be good to go

Answer (score 4):

For anyone struggling with this in Windows XAMPP including PHP 7.3.9:

There is already a libsodium.dll file in c:\xampp\xampp\php.

However, the extension is not activated by default in the php.ini file. Simply edit the file as @Alshoja indicated. In fact, the needed entry is already there but commented out, simply remove the comment:

```
#extension=sodium;
```

to

```
extension=sodium;
```

Restart the server, then verify through phpinfo(); and searching for "sodium" you should now see a "sodium support" column with associated information.

Answer (score 3):

**This answer is only for Linux(Ubuntu) users**

There is default PHP installed as a system package but if you are using self contained installation of PHP (XAMPP [Binami]) then you have to provide **php-config** path in following attribute of `./configure` command while installing the LIBSODIUM for your PHP.

> --with-php-config

I have installed xampp-linux-x64-7.4.15-0 and surprisingly there is no sodium PHP module in this setup. I installed [Sodium library](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium) first and then install [PHP Libsodium](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium-php) extesnion for XAMPP.

```
/opt/lampp/etc/php -m    //Check if you have sodium installed 

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential libtool autoconf
```

Download stable version of Sodium Library by following link

https://doc.libsodium.org/

```
//Go inside the package folder

cd <downloaded package dir>

./configure 
make
sudo make install
```

It will install library and you can check inside the `/usr/local/lib/`. The file for libsodium has been created with *so* extension.

Now we will download and install PHP library for

https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium-php

//Go inside the package folder

```
cd <downloaded package dir>

./configure --with-php-config=/opt/lampp/bin/php-config   //This time we provided preferred php config
make
sudo make install
```

This will isntall extension for XAMPP PHP and you can check `sodium.so` file has been created inside `/opt/lampp7.4/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-2019****`.

**Add extension inside php.ini**

sudo bash -c 'echo "extension="sodium.so"" >> /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini'

Restart XAMPP and check installed php modules

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart

/opt/lampp/etc/php -m
```

If all works fine then you will find sodium in list defiantly.

**CHEERS**

Comment: Thank you for this. After hours/days of research, I finally found this. To add, libsodium-php has changed the way its configured, to install, it is stated on the repo to use the commande 
sudo pecl install -f libsodium

For xampp users, the pecl command will not exist. But the binary is found in /opt/lampp/bin/ so you can add it to your $PATH

Comment: agreed, to be more clear if you are using xampp you can simply do, `sudo apt install libsodium-dev` and then `sudo /opt/lampp/bin/pecl install -f libsodium` instead of compiling the .so from source

Answer (score 1):

this error could be raised by "httpd" on windows xampp because libsodium.dll is not loaded.
however, you can solve it by adding the path of the DLL file to :

> "C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-xampp.conf"

then add the line

```
loadFile "C:/xampp/php/libsodium.dll"
```

[solving libsodium.dll is not found or loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHzQh.png)

finally restart your apache server, and you will be ok