# PHP Sodium not installed?

Tags: php, cryptography, sodium

I'm trying to use Libsodium for the first time to for encryption, but I've encountered an error. I'm running everything on XAMPP; sodium is in the /ext/ folder and I've added `extension=sodium` to the php.ini file.

This is my code.

```php
// This refers to the previous code block.
require "safeCrypto.php"; 

// Do this once then store it somehow:
$key = random_bytes(SODIUM_CRYPTO_SECRETBOX_KEYBYTES);
$message = 'We are all living in a yellow submarine';

$ciphertext = safeEncrypt($message, $key);
$plaintext = safeDecrypt($ciphertext, $key);

echo $ciphertext;
echo $plaintext;
echo phpversion();
```

It throws this error.

> **Warning**:  Use of undefined constant SODIUM_CRYPTO_SECRETBOX_KEYBYTES - assumed 'SODIUM_CRYPTO_SECRETBOX_KEYBYTES' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in **D:\xampp\htdocs\php\crypttest.php** on line **6**
> **Fatal error**:  Uncaught TypeError: random_bytes() expects parameter 1 to be integer, string given in D:\xampp\htdocs\php\crypttest.php:6

`get_loaded_extensions()` shows that sodium is NOT installed, and I can't figure out why. The *php_sodium.dll* file  exists in the ext folder and I've added `extension=sodium` in the php.ini file.

I'm using PHP 7.2.10.

Comment: Have you restarted Apache after changing php.ini?

Comment: @JiriHrazdil Yes, I also removed curl from the extension list before reloading, so I know that the extension list "works". Why do some extensions in php.ini have a semi colon though?

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem last weekend.
I have a fresh installation of Windows 10 to use as my new development machine
I also installed JDK with Apache Netbeans 11.1
And a new installation of XAMMP (xampp-windows-x64-7.3.11-0-VC15-installer)
After installation I modified the php.ini to uncomment the "extension=sodium" and started to check if sodium was active in php with the command "php -m" in the xampp shell. There I saw that the module of sodium was loaded.

In my test.php I put in the line:

```
     <?php
       echo random_bytes(SODIUM_CRYPTO_SECRETBOX_KEYBYTES);
      ?>
```

To check if it worked. Sadly I got an error:

```
 Warning: Use of undefined constant SODIUM_CRYPTO_SECRETBOX_KEYBYTES - assumed 'SODIUM_CRYPTO_SECRETBOX_KEYBYTES' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)
```

I did extended research on this and other forums to find an aswer but did not find one until I tried the method of Jim (https://stackoverflow.com/a/49142981/10509146)
He did go back to an earlier version of php, but the answer is in his step 4. Copy libsodium.dll to the "apache/bin" folder.
And libsodium worked!
I deinstalled Xampp completly and tried it again.
With the same result.
All you need to do is to copy the libsodium.dll from the "xampp/php" folder to the "xampp/apache/bin" folder and ofcourse uncomment the extension in php.ini and you are good to go.