# Need help installing Shopware6 on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, installation, shopware

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.2 on VMWare and I installed xampp-linux-x64-7.4.3.0 on ubuntu system.
I tried to install shopware6 on ubuntu, but I got this error on "System requirements" step.

[Error detail image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfipH.png)

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install / activate the php-sodium PHP extension in your XAMPP.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I installed php-sodium PHP extension.
How can I activate it?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48931914/288568