# There was a problem installing VichUploaderBundle

Tags: php, symfony

I'm a junior in programming. I want to start a new project in the symfony framework in php.

When I try this command for installing VichUploaderBundle in terminal:

```
composer require vich/uploader-bundle
```

I get this error in terminal:

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>
> - lcobucci/jwt 4.3.0 requires ext-sodium * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's sodium extension.
> - lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle v2.18.1 requires lcobucci/jwt ^3.4|^4.0 -> satisfiable by lcobucci/jwt[4.3.0].
> - lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle is locked to version v2.18.1 and an update of this package was not requested.
>
> To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
>
> - C:\xampp\php\php.ini
>   You can also run `php --ini` in a terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
>   Alternatively, you can run Composer with `--ignore-platform-req=ext-sodium` to temporarily ignore these required extensions.
>   You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version   constraint, e.g. "composer require vich/uploader-bundle:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require vich/uploader-bundle:^2.1" if you know which you need.
>
> Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content."

How to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Composer, before installing a library, checks that the necessary extensions are present. Apparently, in your installation, the Sodium extension is missing, and you need to install it beforehand. There are two steps to do this: place the required DLL in the PHP extensions directory and enable the extension in the php.ini file. From what I know, with XAMPP, it's quite straightforward because the DLL library is already there. So, you just need to edit the php.ini file and remove the comment before `#extension=sodium`.

[Here is a question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48287186/sodium-is-not-loading-on-xampp-php-7-2) to install it on XAMPP.

Once the extension is installed, then you can proceed with the installation of VichUploaderBundle .